# Nonsequential cells with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

My desire is to treat an excel row like an array and grab only a couple of cells from each row. The cells will be from the same column each time. Something like this:

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
      new_row = []
      new_row += row[1]
      new_row += row[3]
```

I am having a hard time finding good info on this from the docs.

Edit: I would also be open to ways to achieve this using some python method other than the openpyxl package.

Comment: I don't see any problems, that should work fine.

Comment: It does not because the type of row[3] is a generator, not a primitive.

Comment: No, iter_rows() is generator of tuples.

Comment: The code above throws a TypeError: 'ReadOnlyCell' object is not iterable.

Comment: You should be using append() to add the cells not +=.

Comment: Negative, sir. That fills the new_rows list with contents like <Cell Sheet1.B1>, <Cell Sheet1.D1>,...

Comment: Thanks for downvoting me, btw. You've been a great help.

Comment: Your question says that you want the **cells**. If you want just the values then access use the `.value` property. This is all covered in the documentation.

Comment: A little late in coming with this one. As I said, I was having trouble finding the information in the documentation, which is not well organized. I didn't assume the information wasn't there.

Comment: Seeing as you struggle with adding an element to a list in Python I don't think the problem is the documentation.

Comment: I add an element to a list just fine. It was you who suggested append() when it wasn't necessary. My trouble was knowing that the openpyxl specifically required a reference to .value. This is not immediately apparent from the docs without significant digging.

Comment: Creating a new list to add it to another one? Well, if you like that sort of thing. The openpyxl documentation is extremely clear that cells are objects and your question specifically asked about cells and not cell values. But, by all means, blame the documentation for your imprecise question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it was a matter of specifying row[i].value, as well as throwing brackets around it.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("myfile.xlsx", use_iterators=True)
ws = wb.active

data = []
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    new_row = []
    new_row += [row[1].value]
    new_row += [row[3].value]
    data += new_row
```